# Regex: matching sql params without double quotes

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am dealing with an SQL injection and I need to replace sql params in coldfusion querytags by cfquerparam tags.
For this I am matching anything that looks like the params in this:

```
select * from table
where
test = #var2#,
test ='#var3#'
test2 like '%#test#%'
test3 like '%#test#'
test4 like '#test#%'
```

but not

```
<cfqueryparam value="#test123#">
```

The current regex I have is:

```
[%']?#([^#]*)#['%]?
```

This will currently find all sql params, but also the test123 in the cfqueryparam.
What I need to do, and where I am not succeeding, is exclude `#param#` surrounded by double quotes.
So, no `"#test123#"` but all the ones are fine.

I tried adding `[^"]?` in front of it, but then it also starts selecting others characters in front of the match. Same happens in the back.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use cfqueryparam, this will bind the parameters and prevent any kind of SQL injection.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html

You can actually use the % inside the tag as such:

```
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#test#%" />
```

Comment: From my reading of the question the asker already knows that he wants to use `cfqueryparam`, but that he's trying to find all of the places where it's currently missing and needs help with regex in the search.

Comment: Correct. I know exactly how to prevent it, but I my regex is 99% done, it just need a little bit of help to get my regex to NOT match "%test%" (including the double quotes).
With the current regex, I still need to check for double quotes around the returned value from the regex and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

seems to me that you just don't want the ? in [^"]?
This works for me: `[%'][^"]?#([^#]*)#['%]?`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thanks.
I did need to alter it a bit, this one works perfect for me:

[%']?[^"]#([^#]*)#['%]?

on this example:

select *, '#attrivutes.name#' from table
where
test = #var2#,
test ='#var3#'
test2 like '%#test#%'
test3 like '%#test#'
test4 like '#test#%'

(drop it in http://www.regextester.com/)

Only minor issue is that it also catches the space infront of #var2#, but that is not a big issue for now. If anyone knows how to fix that, I would be very happy to learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, this one seems to be a bit more complete:

[']?[%]?[^"]#([^#]*)#[%]?[']?

separating the ['%]? into [']?[%]? seem to be better, otherwise it removed a comma in the statement 
insert into bla (col1, col2)
values ('#val1#','#val2#')